# Mongoose won't connect to Mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to an mlab database from a node app and it is just hanging when I try to connect.  It also is showing the default port 27017 in the error even though my mlab database uses a different port.

I have used mlab and mongoose on other projects and never received this error so am very confused.

The error:

```
{ MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/<user>/playground/mongo-test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:308:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason:
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <my username> <my username>:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<my username>:<my password>@<theservername>.mlab.com:59577/express-chat-dev', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err) => {
    console.log('[hello]');
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('[mongo connected]');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Express running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Your code perfectly worked for me without any changes. It might be a problem with your URI (credentials format) or network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if it's an API change, but moving my credentials into the options object fixed my issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const options = {
  user: <username>, 
  pass: <password>, 
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<theservername>.mlab.com:59577/express-chat-dev', options, (err) => {
    console.log('[hello]');
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('[mongo connected]');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Express running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```